# MVC querying in view or in controller, with different results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET MVC app using Visual Studio 2019, but I have some problems with partial view querying.

If I compose the queries in the view and call the `@Html.partial`, they run, else if I compose the queries in the controller and create partial views, when I call the `@Html.partial` they don't run correctly.

Is there any problem about performance or any other issues? what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code:

**(1)** case running correctly

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<archea.Models.T_Anagrafica>

@Html.Partial("_Index", Model.Where(p => p.Cliente == true))
```

Controller:

```
// GET: T_Anagrafica
public ActionResult _Index()
{
    return PartialView(db.T_Anagrafica.OrderBy(den => den.Denominazione).ToList());
}
```

**(2)** case NOT running

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<archea.Models.T_Anagrafica>
@Html.Partial("_IndexClienti")
```

Controller:

```
// GET: T_Anagrafica
public ActionResult _IndexClienti()
{
    return View(db.T_Anagrafica.Where(p => p.Cliente == true).OrderBy(den => den.Denominazione).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for "_IndexClienti" view also to get better idea

Comment: Can you please check `@Html.Partial("_IndexClienti",Model)`

Comment: Using `Partial` you want to call Controller action?

Comment: @jishansiddique, the query doesn't rgive the correct results

Comment: @Alberto, if you render a partial view inside main view and your view have model class you need to send with partial helper.

Comment: @jishansiddique Could you please send me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here its some explnation for you

I m bit confused How your 1st case running but it's ok because without complete code its hard to answer. While working with MVC you must understand this 4 methods

```
Html.Partial
Html.RenderPartial
Html.Action
Html.RenderAction
```

There are 2 different places where you are populating or applying sorting on result but it must be done at one place only, so with your 1st case it must look like this

```
db.T_Anagrafica.Where(p => p.Cliente == true).OrderBy(den => den.Denominazione).ToList()
```

in your 2nd case, you are using Html.Partial, if you understand this method then you must understand that you have to pass @Model as parameter, if you dont pass then it wont display anything as you create components based on model items

another approach is with RenderAction, I suggest you go through with them

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

> Controller code

```
public ActionResult _IndexClienti()
{
     var data=db.T_Anagrafica.Where(p => p.Cliente == true).OrderBy(den => den.Denominazione).ToList();
    return PartialView(data);
}
```

> View "_IndexClienti" must be the same name with action or you need to return like eg  `return PartialView("_IndexClienti",data);`

```
@model IEnumerable<archea.Models.T_Anagrafica>
<h3>Clienti</h3>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th class="small">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdAnagrafica)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Denominazione)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Indirizzo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CF)/<BR>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PIVA)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tel)<BR>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FAX)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodAnacf)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fornitore)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cliente)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ente)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="small">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdAnagrafica)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Denominazione)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Indirizzo)<BR>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CAP) -
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Citta)
                (@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Provincia))
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CF)<BR>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PIVA)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tel)<br>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FAX)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodAnacf)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fornitore)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cliente)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ente)
            </td>
            <td>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", new { Controller = "T_Anagrafica", action = "Edit", id = item.IdAnagrafica })' class="btn btn-success">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", new { Controller = "T_Anagrafica", action = "Details", id = item.IdAnagrafica })' class="btn btn-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", new { Controller = "T_Anagrafica", action = "Delete", id = item.IdAnagrafica })' class="btn btn-danger">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't run, I'm doing something wrong because if i launch the partialview _IndexClienti address directly in the browser I obtain the right results obviusly without _layout aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jigar Sangoi, I resolve my issue using RenderAction as follow:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("_IndexClienti", "T_Anagrafica");}
```

Thanks to all